# User input conversion in Dart. Getting error for empty string

Tags: dart

I am new to learning dart and was studying the topic of user input conversion in dart. I tried the following code:

```
void main() {
  print("Enter a number: ");
  String? strNum = stdin.readLineSync();
  print("Your input is: $strNum"); //Shows an empty string
  if (strNum == "") {
    strNum == "0";
  }
  int num = int.parse(strNum!);
  int result = num + 10;
  print("The result is $result");
}
```

I used an if condition but I keep getting an error- Unhandled exception:
FormatException: Invalid number (at character 1)

I also tried using tryParse.

```
void main() {
  print("Enter a number: ");
  String? strNum = stdin.readLineSync();
  print("Your input is: $strNum"); // Shows an empty string
  if (strNum == "") {
    strNum == "0";
  }
  int num = int.tryParse(strNum!)!;
  int result = num + 10;
  print("The result is $result");
}
```

In this case i get the error- Unhandled exception:
Null check operator used on a null value

How do I resolve this?

Dart version: stable 2.19.6

Comment: That's the error you would expect if the input string wasn't a valid number. try adding `print("Your input: '$strNum'");` before the parse attempt to see what the actual value of the string is.

Comment: Also, if you're in a situation like this where the input can possibly not be a valid number, it's better practice to use `tryParse` which will return null instead of throwing an error.

Comment: @Abion47 I edited the question. Can you check again?

Comment: The purpose of using `tryCatch` to get a null is that when it returns null, the input wasn't a valid number. Using `!` to coerce the nullish value into a non-null value is defeating the whole point since if the value is null, it's not a number and you shouldn't be working with it anyway. Also, if `strNum` is empty, what are you typing into the terminal as input?

Comment: Notice the extra `=` in `strNum == "0";`. You never assign `"0"` to `strNum`.

I'd also recommend doing `strNum = strNum.trim();` before checking whether the string is empty, in case the user entered a leading or trailing space.

Comment: @Abion47 thanks for the syntax check. strNum is empty as when the terminal prompts for an input I just pressed enter as I was trying to see what would happen if the user did not input any value. I thought the input I was getting was null but it was actually an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. You can convert user input even if you enter an empty string. The error in the question was that I put '==' in the if condition block. Thank you @Abion47 for pointing it out. Now the following code works when you pass in an empty string:

```
print("Enter a number: ");
  String? strNum = stdin.readLineSync();
  strNum = strNum!.replaceAll(new RegExp(r"\D"), ""); // removes all chracters except digits
  
  if (strNum.isEmpty) {
    strNum = "0";
  }
  int num = int.parse(strNum);
  int result = num + 10;
  print("The result is $result");
}
```

I also added the replaceAll function with RegExp that removes every character other than digits from the string in case user enters a bad input.

Comment: This will work when the user doesn't enter in any input, but if the user enters in bad input (like "abc"), it will crash. The better solution is to use `int? n = int.tryParse(strNum); if (n == null) { ... }` as it will catch any situation in which the string is not a number.

Comment: Modified the answer to deal with all exceptions! Now it won't crash.

Answer (score 0):

You must handle the exception properly. For ex, in your code block. when user inputs a string, app will crash. Try this.

```
void main() {
  try {
    print("Enter a number: ");
    String? strNum = stdin.readLineSync();
    int num = int.parse(strNum);
    int result = num + 10;
    print("The result is $result");
  } catch (ex) {
    print(ex);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! I edited the question. It was actually not a null but an empty string being passed. So a try-catch block doesn't work.